# Minimax algorithm logic outputting unexpected results

Tags: java, chess, minimax

I am making a minimax algorithm for a simple chess engine, however have run in to some difficulties. I have run through my code for hours and to no avail, it seems to still output the wrong results; when I threaten one of its pieces and it has a valid move that would save the piece, it ignores the move.

Below, I have simplified the code of the minimax algorithm method as much as possible to try and show what I was trying to achieve and hopefully make the mistake visible. It is initially called with minimax(2,true);

```
public static int[] minimax(int depth, boolean max) {
    int piece = 0;
    int square = 0;
    int boardScore = 0;
    int bestScore = -9999;
    if (!max) {
        bestScore = 9999;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 64; b++) {
            boardScore = 0;
            boolean valid = false;
            if (max) {
                valid = Board[a].validate(b, aiColor);
            } else {
                valid = Board[a].validate(b, playerColor);
            }

            if (valid) {
                storePosition(depth-1);
                if (max) {
                    Board[a].move(b,aiColor);
                } else {
                    Board[a].move(b,playerColor);
                }

                boardScore = calculateScore();
                if (depth != 1) {
                    if (max) {
                        int[] minimaxArray = minimax(depth-1, false);
                        boardScore = minimaxArray[2];
                    } else {
                        int[] minimaxArray = minimax(depth-1, true);
                        boardScore = minimaxArray[2];
                    }

                }
                if (boardScore > bestScore && max) {
                    piece = a;
                    square = b;
                    bestScore = boardScore;
                }
                if (boardScore < bestScore && !max) {
                    piece = a;
                    square = b;
                    bestScore = boardScore;
                }
                resetPosition(depth-1);
            }

        }
    }
    int[] returnVars = new int[3];
    returnVars[0] = piece;
    returnVars[1] = square;
    returnVars[2] = bestScore;
    return returnVars;
}
```

I am certain that the other methods work perfectly, as move() simply changes the piece, validate() is correct as it works when it displays all of the moves a player can make, calculateScore() is correct as it simply counts the instances of the pieces and totals the scores depending on the colour of them. (If the ai is a knight ahead, the score would be 3; if the player is a pawn ahead, the score would be -1).

The program seems to still not follow the logic I would like it to however, and does not move its pieces away when threatened. For example, I moved a pawn so that it could take the bot's knight, and it failed to move the knight away.

This is one example of its mistakes, and makes me believe there is a problem with my logic in calculating the best move / its recursion being done incorrectly, however it could be calculateScore(), so I will add that as well.

```
public static int calculateScore() {
    int boardScore = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < 64; c++) {
        if (Board[c].color.equals(aiColor)) {
            boardScore += Board[c].points;
        } else {
            boardScore -= Board[c].points;
        }
    }
    return boardScore;
}
```

Comment: It seems you're changing `Board` instead of making a copy of it or rolling back.

Comment: In resetPosition(depth-1), it resets the board back to the state it was before the move was made. It 'undoes' the move that was made to test its value / to continue to the next depth of the algorithm. To try and simplify the code I removed the storePosition(depth-1) method as I had seen others simply use game.undo(), but I will add it in to reduce confusion

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this error was not a problem with logic and instead was a problem with my methods, even after my statement of "I am certain that the other methods work perfectly". It turns out that the problem was due to validating the pieces moving.

In chess there is an obscure rule of 'en passant' where a pawn that has just moved forwards two acts differently to one that has not just been moved forwards two squares. For this reason I had a class for these pieces and replaced instances of them with regular pawns at the end of a regular move, however as these test moves were not regular moves, it did not remove the movedTwoPawn, and thought that it could not move, as in regular play the movedTwoPawn can never be moved.

To fix this problem, I added in the replacing of the movedTwoPawns with regular Pawns and it works perfectly.